# Using Mac Sierra's siri feature to test xcode app on simulator

Tags: ios10, macos-sierra

I have upgraded Mac system to sierra and xcode to 8.0.My question is,Is it possible to use siri of Mac system to test xcode app on simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Mac Sierra's SIRI feature because IOS simulator have its own SIRI activated ...

You just need to  update your **XCode Version :8.3.1** and above support SIRI in simulator.

Enable SIRI from Settings in Simulator 
**Hardware--->SIRI-->DONE-Start testing**